# li toggle visibility of active class

Tags: jquery, css

I have a small script that I am trying to toggle the visibility of list items with an active class. The script itself is working, but I am having a bit of an issue conceptualizing how to always have the visible item at the top.

Basically, I would like the active item to show at the top, and other non-active li elements should disappear. How do I achieve this?

Here is what I have so far:

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/353t69c6/1/)**

html:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item active">test 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">test 2</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">test 3</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">test 4</li>
</ul>

<button class="next btn btn-primary">Click</button>
```

css:

```
.list-group-item {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.list-group-item.active {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

jquery:

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    $('.list-group-item.active').next().addClass('active');
    $('.list-group-item.active').prev().removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: exclude the first li..

Comment: Question unclear, will attempt to clarify. Answer to follow: Instead of modifying "visibility" in the CSS, modify "display".

Comment: you cant transition display

Comment: Fair, but you can transition height...

Comment: Simply use `display:none;` instead of `visibility:hidden;`

Comment: i had tried height initially and this is the result https://jsfiddle.net/353t69c6/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqsinger/khqn5qma/2/)

To achieve the desired effect here, I would update the CSS so that you transition height as well as visibility. It's helpful to also set the height, margin, padding, and border of invisible (non-active) elements all to zero as well, as in:

```
.list-group-item {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    display:block;

    height: 0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;

    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.list-group-item > * {
    display:none;
    height:0;
}

.list-group-item.active {
    visibility: visible;
    height:100px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.list-group-item.active > * {
    display:none;
}
```

This way, active items may glide up to the top of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Use this updated `CSS`

```
.list-group-item {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    display: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.list-group-item.active {
    display: block;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/353t69c6/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try below css. I have changed only display property using js to smoothen the transition.
Here is updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/353t69c6/6/

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    $('.list-group-item.active').next().addClass('active');
    $('.list-group-item.active').prev().removeClass('active');

    setTimeout(function(){$('.list-group-item').hide();$('.list-group-item.active').show()} ,500);
});
```

css is same

```
.list-group-item {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.list-group-item.active {
    visibility: visible!important;
}
```

Comment: only challenge with this is that i lose my transitions

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `position` to achieve this, make the `active` li `position` `absolute` to the parent element and add `top:0` like,

```js
$('.next').click(function() {
    var $a=$('.list-group-item.active');
    $('.list-group-item.active').removeClass('active');
    // wait to hide active element
    setTimeout(function(){$a.next().addClass('active');},1000);    
});
```

```css
.list-group-item {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.list-group{
    position:relative;
}

.list-group-item.active {
    visibility: visible;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;    
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item active">test 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">test 2</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">test 3</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">test 4</li>
</ul>

<button class="next btn btn-primary">Click</button>
```

Updated for jumping issue

```js
$('.next').click(function () {
    var $a = $('.list-group-item.active').next();
    $('.list-group-item.active').removeClass('active');
    if (!$a.length) {
        $a = $('.list-group-item:first');
    }
    // wait to hide active element
    setTimeout(function () {
        // add position and get into top
        $a.addClass('active').css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': 0,
            'width': '100%'
        });
        $('.list-group-item:not(.active)').removeAttr('style');
        if($a.prev().length){
         //$a.prev().removeAttr('style');
        } else {
            //$('.list-group-item:first').removeAttr('style');
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.list-group-item {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.list-group {
    position:relative;
}
.list-group-item.active {
    visibility: visible;
    /*position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item active" style="position:absolute;top:0;width:100%">test 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">test 2</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">test 3</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">test 4</li>
</ul>
<button class="next btn btn-primary">Click</button>
```

Comment: This is cool, but it makes for a jumpy animation. The active item jumps from its original place up to the top in an unusual fashion.